# SSL certificate in postman Mac verifiy failure

Tags: ssl-certificate, postman

I am trying to call some REST API toward the server authorises only certificates. I have set the certificates in Postman (.crt, .key and .pfx files and passphrase). But when I make a REST API call, I see Postman console logs that certificate files are included in the request but I get 
`Error: mac verify failure`
I searched on internet and found some conversations suggesting this error is caused by wrong or missing passphrase, but I am sure I am providing correct passphrase (the one I set when converting pfx file to .crt file).
I am not sure if I should provide the passphrase I set while converting pfx file to crt file or somthing else?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can you please add more details to this question? Is quite hard to see whats going on here without looking on your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to select only the CRT and Key files and leave PFX empty.
If you used a passphrease for generating the CRT File, you have to put it in the "passphrase" field. Otherwise leave "passphrase" blank.

If its still not working, please provide more informations.

Comment: I removed pfx file from postman and it works. Thank you very much!